# Odd Margin Behavior; Parsing Issue? Obscure Aspect Setting Issue? Clueless

Tags: html, css, browser, html-parsing, settings

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CciPU.png)

In the top example of vertical div elements, the proper spacing of 2 pixels only appears between the second and the third. All others are only one.

In the bottom example of horizontal inline-block div elements, you have a weird every other result. 2px, 1px, 2px, 1px...

The HTML is simple and uniform...

```
<div style="width:14px;">
<div style="height:12px; background:red; margin:1px;"></div>
<div style="height:12px; background:red; margin:1px;"></div>
<div style="height:12px; background:red; margin:1px;"></div>
<div style="height:12px; background:red; margin:1px;"></div>
<div style="height:12px; background:red; margin:1px;"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="height:12px; width:12px; background:red; margin:1px; display:inline-block;"></div><!--
--><div style="height:12px; width:12px; background:red; margin:1px; display:inline-block;"></div><!--
--><div style="height:12px; width:12px; background:red; margin:1px; display:inline-block;"></div><!--
--><div style="height:12px; width:12px; background:red; margin:1px; display:inline-block;"></div><!--
--><div style="height:12px; width:12px; background:red; margin:1px; display:inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

and yet we get the linked image.

I've tried to find an answer but most "odd gapping div element" questions involve content within the divs or not commenting out white space (which I did in the inline-block example).

This isn't really a "I need a solution for my problem" question,
because I'm simply going to create a grid wrapper.
It's just a general understanding question
because it just seems like a weird result for such a straight forward input.

What causes this behavior?

**EDIT:** Emailed example to another pc which rendered margin spacing properly in Brave.
Wondering if obscure HTML parsing bug? Uninstalled and reinstalled Brave on original pc with issue, odd spacing persists.
Zoom at 100%. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4hsP.png)

Currently, no idea what is causing the problem.

Comment: Just a note that the spacing is consistent when run as an embedded snippet and I copy pasted your code into an html document and opened it with chrome and also saw consistent spacing so I have to ask what browser are you using?

Comment: @kpie Thanks. I'm currently using Brave v1.35.103. I just opened the page in Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102 (current) and still have the same odd spacing... very weird.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your zoom is set to something like 125%. Set your browser zoom to 100% and you will observe consistent results.